# How to export multiple charts asp.net to a single document PDF using itextSharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, asp.net-charts

I want to export two Charts Asp.net to a single document PDF using iTextSharp.

For one chart, I could do it :

```
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Chart1.SaveImage(stream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
    iTextSharp.text.Image chartImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(stream.GetBuffer());
    chartImage.ScalePercent(75f);
    pdfDoc.Add(chartImage);
    pdfDoc.Close();

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Charts.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
```

BUT, I can't export two Charts in the same time...

Someone has the answer ? thank you very much...

Comment: How about doing the same for `Chart2` before `pdfDoc.Close()` as you did for `Chart1`?

Comment: I already did the same for Chart2, but he result is that the first Chart1 is duplicated twice !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're referencing the same chart, or not cleaning up the `MemoryStream`? Here's a simple example that generates two different charts, and then adds them to the `Document`.

First a helper method to generate some sample data:

```
byte[] GetChartImage(params int[] points)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var chart = new Chart())
        {
            chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
            Series s = new Series();
            for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; ++i)
            {
                s.Points.AddXY(points[i], points[i]);
            }
            chart.Series.Add(s);
            chart.SaveImage(stream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
        }
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then add the charts:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=charts.pdf");
using (Document document = new Document())
{
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
    document.Open();
    document.Add(Image.GetInstance(GetChartImage(3, 5, 7)));
    document.Add(Image.GetInstance(GetChartImage(2, 4, 6, 8)));
}
Response.End();
```

The PDF output:

[image]

Comment: You are Right. I'm not cleaning up the MemoryStream ! Thank you very much. It's OK now.